# WiringTrouble With replacing blower motor in my furnace

Tags: furnace, replacement, rewire

When replacing the blower motor in my furnace I notice the old blower motor had a Brown and a Brown and white wire going to the furnace off of the motor the new motor however does not Instead it has an additional green wire which typically would be ground But I see it has a green and yellow wire grounding the blower motor to the housing. What do I do with this additional green wire Coming off the blower motor and the open Brown and Brown and white wire coming off my furnace

Comment: When I replaced mine, there was an extra wire was for running it a different speeds.  I picked the one that seemed to match the old blower.

Comment: Well i have 2 extra wires coming off my furnace more specifically they come off the capacitor and went to the old blower motor.

Comment: Perhaps the new motor has a builtin starting capacitor.  Can you please post a photo of the connection diagram on the motor housing?

Comment: Also check the rotation on the old motor. Sometimes motors can go in either direction an the extra wire is for that. We need a picture of the nameplate and hookup diagram.

Comment: Note that for items like this, you can't assume anything about the colors of the wires, and you really need to find a wiring diagram or a schematic printed on the component.  Some colors are relatively "standard" but not guaranteed.  (in other words, you have no idea what the green or brown wires do just because of their colors)

Comment: If you can post the motor model number we may be able to help yellow is not normally grounded.